# Change shortcut for auto-completion in Texstudio

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion, shortcut

I want to change auto-completion keyboard shortcut in Texstudio. Currently, it is set to Ctrl+Space and I wish to change it to a more convenient Shift+Enter. How do I do that? 'Shortcut' tab in Preferences doesn't display the shortcut for the auto-completion feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Shortcut tab` click on `Idefix` then on `Completetion` and you'll find <kbd>Ctrl+Space</kbd>  shortcut. You can simply change it as you wish.